# Camelia with virus?

Tags: diagnosis, plant-health, diseases, leaves

What is the problem with this white camellia? Some leaves are getting completely yellow but the plant is generally very vigorous. Is it virus? Is there a treatment?[image]

Comment: Please see https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/36537/what-is-causing-yellow-discoloration-on-the-leaves-of-my-camellia which appears to have an answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be correct.  A virus can cause this but it could also be a hidden genotype that surfaced. A reversal so to speak. Usually you see variegated plants reverting having branches of solid green.

Variegated plants are less hardy than their solid green cousins.  Where there is white there is no photosynthesis happening, no making food/energy for the plant's use.  Worse, variegated plants in low light are even more hampered.  Still, they brighten a room with the punch of white or yellow.

[virus variegation](https://www.sgaonline.org.au/virus-or-variegation/)

[variegation problems](https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/plant-problems/environmental/variegated-plant-problems.htm)